# Feature Detect Autoplay HTML5 Audio - Audio on Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html, iphone

So I have a site where users would want to demo audio output produced by a server side script. They select some options and hit a create button. I then AJAX in a HTML5 audio element in with the autoplay attribute set to true. This works great on desktops, not so much on mobile.

My workaround until now was to use a PHP code snippet to determine from the user-agent string whether the device accessing my site was a mobile device. I would then display the HTML5 audio player so the user could hit the play button to still play the audio.

The thing is, user-agent string to detect mobile is now not working for newer phones. So my bad practice has finally come back to haunt me. Is there a way to feature detect for the ability to autoplay audio?

Comment: could you not just explicitly call play with js after the ajax call

Comment: @kalpaitch can you? My impression was that on mobile the user has to explicitly play audio to avoid unwanted bandwidth usage.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120703/how-do-i-detect-if-the-html5-autoplay-attribute-is-supported

Comment: http://mrcoles.com/detecting-html5-audio-autoplay/

Comment: @Zenith You should post that link with a little more information in an answer. I am going to try that out tomorrow and if that works you get the bounty! As far as I can tell modernizr cannot detect `autoplay`

Comment: @thatidiotguy Did you test it? How did it work out?

Comment: @Zenith With a few modifications yes it did work. Post an answer and I will accept yours. Just please point to the code I post as well so that people can see the code I actually used to detect the feature. Thanks again for the great link.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there are indeed ways to do so.

The following is a short tried-and-tested example of detecting browser support of the autoplay attribute which you could use for both desktop and mobile browsers featured on [**GitHub**](https://gist.github.com/mrcoles/5537536).

The example is as follows, with comments from myself explaining how it works:

```
var AUTOPLAY = false; // A flag to be used in the anonymous function

(function() {

    // Audio file data URIs; MP3 + OGG
    var mp3 = 'data:audio/mpeg;base64,/+MYxAAAAANIAUAAAASEEB/jwOFM/0MM/90b/+RhST//w4NFwOjf///PZu////9lns5GFDv//l9GlUIEEIAAAgIg8Ir/JGq3/+MYxDsLIj5QMYcoAP0dv9HIjUcH//yYSg+CIbkGP//8w0bLVjUP///3Z0x5QCAv/yLjwtGKTEFNRTMuOTeqqqqqqqqqqqqq/+MYxEkNmdJkUYc4AKqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq';
    var ogg = 'data:audio/ogg;base64,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';

    try {
        var audio = new Audio(); // Construct new Audio object
        var src = audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? ogg : mp3; // Ternary statement determining the value of the src variable, which will be either ogg or mp3.
        audio.autoplay = true; // Set autoplay to true

        // This event will only be triggered if setting the autoplay attribute to true works.             
        $(audio).on('play', function() {
            AUTOPLAY = true; // Set the global flag to true, indicating we have support.
        });

        audio.src = src; // Set the audio objects src to the value of the src variable.
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('[AUTOPLAY-ERROR]', e);
        // This means we were unsuccessful - this browser doesn't support the autoplay attribute.
    }
})(); // Invoke anonymous function.
```

There is an example of this snippet in-use over at [**PicDinner.com**](http://picdinner.com/)

For the slightly modified version the OP used for his particular use-case, [**check his answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17836886/1586880).

Comment: I implemented this into my login form and then onsubmit of the form (because this works best when the value is checked after a delay) I then populate the AUTOPLAY value into a hidden field in the login form. Then when the user logs in I can save the value to the session and remember it for their entire experience without needing to execute this on every page.

Comment: The real problem is that this script is crashing on Chrome for mobile.

Comment: Worth noting this requires **jQuery** for the `$(audio).on()` bit. Could probably use `addEventListener` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Help for future answer seekers, an ideal way to check if auto-play supported or not by the browsers/devices:

```
var promise = document.getElementById('video').play();

if( typeof promise !== 'undefined' ) {
    promise.then(function() {
        // auto-play started!
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // auto-play failed
    });
}
```

Please note, media play promise is not supported by all browsers yet. In case if browser doesn't support it, it will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the html page I used to test for autoplay.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            var AUTOPLAY = false;

            $(function() {

                $("#message").html("AUTOPLAY = FALSE");

                // Audio file data URIs from comments in
                // [this gist](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/253174)
                // via [mudcube](https://github.com/mudcube)
                var mp3 = 'data:audio/mpeg;base64,/+MYxAAAAANIAUAAAASEEB/jwOFM/0MM/90b/+RhST//w4NFwOjf///PZu////9lns5GFDv//l9GlUIEEIAAAgIg8Ir/JGq3/+MYxDsLIj5QMYcoAP0dv9HIjUcH//yYSg+CIbkGP//8w0bLVjUP///3Z0x5QCAv/yLjwtGKTEFNRTMuOTeqqqqqqqqqqqqq/+MYxEkNmdJkUYc4AKqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq';

                var ogg = 'data:audio/ogg;base64,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';

                try 
                {
                    var audio = new Audio();
                    var src = audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? ogg : mp3;
                    audio.autoplay = true;
                    audio.volume = 0;

                    $("#message").html("AUTOPLAY = FALSE");

                    // this will only be triggered if autoplay works
                    $(audio).on('play', function() {
                        AUTOPLAY = true;
                        $("#message").html('AUTOPLAY = TRUE');
                    });

                    audio.src = src;
                } 
                catch(e) 
                {
                    $("#message").html('[AUTOPLAY-ERROR]'+e);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="message">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://modernizr.com/ should have everything that you need to implement detection for autoplay audio

Comment: I'm not seeing that as testable in the modernizr documentation. http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5