# Modernizr.videoautoplay object shows true, Modernizr.videoautoplay returning undefined

Tags: modernizr

I'm using a custom Modernizr build, v3.3.0. I've created a simple JSFiddle example to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/cqkg7x45/6/.

```
console.log(Modernizr);
```

will show the Modernizr object, and when I inspect it in the JS console I can see "videoautoplay" is a property with a value of "true".

But, when I do

```
console.log(Modernizr.videoautoplay)
```

it returns "undefined".

I was originally seeing this issue in a WordPress theme I'm developing, but was also able to recreate in JSFiddle and a separate stand-alone HTML page. Also, Modernizr is putting the "videoautoplay" class on my HTML tag, even when I know the device does not support that feature (iPhone 5).

Update: This issue appears to be happening in Chrome (v47.0.2526.106), but not Firefox (v43.0.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question in case anyone else runs into this problem. I found the solution on this SO post: [How do I detect if the HTML5 autoplay attribute is supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120703/how-do-i-detect-if-the-html5-autoplay-attribute-is-supported).

Since this is an "async" test you can't access the property using the syntax

```
Modernizr.videoautoplay
```

You have to use the .on() function, as shown in the above SO post:

```
Modernizr.on('videoautoplay', function(result){
  if(result) {
    alert('video autoplay is supported');
  }  else {
    alert('video autplay is NOT supported');
  }
});
```