# Jest test error rendering landing page with a video component that autoplays

Tags: reactjs, video, jestjs

I have a landing page in react that has a video playing automatically on load.

I get the following error during running the test

```
console.error
  Error: Not implemented: HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play
```

my test code

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';


test('Rendering landing page', () => {
 

/*
  const playStub = jest
    .spyOn(window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'play')
    .mockImplementation(() => {})
  
  // trigger the code that you would expect to call the pause function
  //expect(playStub).toHaveBeenCalled()
  playStub.mockRestore()

*/

  const { container  } = render(<App />);

  const spy = jest.spyOn(window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'play');
  //const isPlaying = video.play();

  //expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  //expect(isPlaying).toBe(true);

  let link = screen.getAllByText('Signin')[0];
  expect(link.href).toContain('/signin-login');  
});
```

---

I tried this and got a different error -- "    console.error
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: promise.then is not a function]"

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

describe("Home Page",function(){
  test('Rendering landing page', async function(){

    Object.defineProperty(window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype, "paused", {
        value:true,
        writable:true
    });
    window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play = function(){
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event('play'));
        this.paused = false;
        return true;
    };
    window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype.pause = function(){
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event('paused'));
        this.paused = true;
        return true;
    };


    render(<App />);

    let link = screen.getAllByText('Signin')[0];
    expect(link.href).toContain('/signin-login');  
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsdom` doesn't support any play or pause media operations. As a workaround you can add a few modificaton in your test setup:

I have `Home` a component:

```
function Home(){

    return(
        <div>
            <video data-testid="video" autoPlay src="./video.webm"></video>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Jest

```
describe("Home Page",function(){

    test("Initial rendering",async function(){
        Object.defineProperty(window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype, "paused", {
            value:true,
            writable:true
        });
        window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play = function(){
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event('play'));
            this.paused = false;
            return Promise.resolve(true);
        };
        window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype.pause = function(){
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event('paused'));
            this.paused = true;
            return Promise.resolve(true);
        };
        render(<Home/>);
        const video = screen.getAllByTestId("video")[0];
        await video.play();
        expect(video.paused).toBe(false);
        await video.pause();
        expect(video.paused).toBe(true);
    })

})
```

Comment: When I add this - I get a new error -- "    console.error  Error: Uncaught [TypeError: promise.then is not a function]"

Comment: Edit your answer that you tried

Comment: Where you are using promise i don't see anything?

Comment: const promise = video.play();

Comment: Play doesn't return promise it return true and it seems you missed something in your edit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293245/html5-video-play-returning-pending-promises

Comment: I see, that is native play but here we are creating but i can change it

Comment: Now check @TheOldCounty